# How do I recognize if someone deposited enough money?

Tags: c#

Example Code:

```
//money deposit
            Console.Write("Enter said ammount of money: ");
            moneyres = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            if (moneyres < ticket)
            {
                double dif = ticket - moneyres;
                Console.Write("Oh, sorry you are " + dif + " dollar(s) sort.\nPlease enter more money so you can purchase the ticket: ");
                double m2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                double m3 = dif - m2;
                while ( m3 > 0 ) 
                {
                    Console.Write("Oh, sorry you are " + m3 + " dollar(s) sort.\nPlease enter more money so you can purchase the ticket: ");

                }
            }
            else if (moneyres > ticket)
            {
                change = moneyres - ticket;
                Console.WriteLine("So your change is: " + change + " dollar(s).\nHere you go. Have fun!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Here you go. Have fun!");
            }
```

So lets say the ticket is 10 bucks and someone puts 5. Then the difference is going to be 5. Then lets say he adds 2 more. How can i do a loop till the amount hits 0? (I am new to coding btw).

Comment: "How do I recognize if someone deposited enough money?" "How can i do a loop till the amount hits 0?" These seem to be two unrelated questions. What is actually the point of confusion?

Comment: You asked "how to loop" - did you actually go and research what looping options are available in C#? Try any of them? What problems did you run into? There's a certain level of research you need to do yourself before coming to ask for help on Stack Overflow. You need to show that you've done the basic research, and include your attempt at incorporating that research into your question. Show us that you have an actual problem - not just a situation where you want us to write the code for you. We're not a code writing service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do all of this in a while loop.

```
double totalValue = 0.0;

while(totalValue < ticket)
{
    Console.Write("Enter said amount of money: ");
    moneyres = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    totalValue += moneyres;

    if (totalValue > ticket)
    {
        // Enough
    } 
    else
    {
       // Not enough
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should look into a while loop. Something like while(UserInput < ticket). UserInput in this case is the amount that the user pays.

Comment: You shouldn't have put this as an answer but a comment. Answers should solve the problem, not tell them what to research. That's what comments are for(and other things as well.)

Answer (score -2):

So I did this. Thanks a lot for the suggestions!

```
double tot = 0.0;
while (tot < ticket)
{
  string sp = "Enter money: ";
  Console.Write(sp);
  moneyres = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
  tot += moneyres;
  if (tot > ticket)
  {
     change = tot - ticket;
     Console.WriteLine("Alright here is your change. That's " + change + " dolars.And 
     here is your ticket!\nEnjoy your ride!");
  }
  else if (tot==ticket)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("That's just perfect! Here you go!\nEnjoy your ride!");
  }
  else
  {
     Console.WriteLine("You did not enter enough money.");
  } 
}
Console.ReadKey();
```